# Adding p:outputLabel for multiple required fileds inside datatable / datagrid

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have simple `Primefaces` `DataTable` , inside this `DataTable` I have a p:outputLabel , I need the for attribute to point multiple inputFields, how I can do it ?

Sample code :

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{mbBasicView.cars}">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <p:outputText value="#{car.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <p:inputText id="carYear" value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:inputText id="carPrice" value="#{car.price}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I want to point car name to year and price, if user not entered the year or / and price, it must rise an required validation message, with highlight (and add start) to car name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found workaround for this issue, with CSS and adding extra label, this maybe helpful for panelGrid also (I think anything inside `<p:column>`) , But I tested it with `DataTable` only:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{mbBasicView.cars}">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <p:outputText styleClass="car-name" for="carYear" value="#{car.name}" />
        <p:outputText styleClass="car-name" for="carPrice" value="#{car.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <p:inputText id="carYear" value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:inputText id="carPrice" value="#{car.price}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And css style that hide filed if another is error state or duplicated:

```
.car-name {
   display:none;
}

.car-name.ui-state-error {
   display:block;
}
.car-name ~ .car-name {
   display:block;
}
.car-name ~ .car-name.ui-state-error {
   display:block;
}

.car-name.ui-state-error ~ .car-name{
   display:none;
}
```

Hope this will be helpful, in case you have more than 2 fields it will work except if you have 2 normal labels then error label, I think you can play around this case with another style class, play around the CSS magic will do awesome work.